# What is the mixed strategy equilibrium bid, if any, for complete information auction games with minimum bid?

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider the following complete-information, auction game. There are two players $i=1,2$. Each bids simultaneously a value $b_i\in[0,\infty)$. The payoff function is symmetric:

$$
\pi_i =\begin{cases}
a - b_i & \text{if } b_i > \max\{b_j,\bar b\} \\
(a - b_i)/2 & \text{if } b_i = b_j \geq \bar b \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\bar b$ is a minimum bid required to win a prize $a>0$.

What is the **mixed strategy** equilibrium, if any, of this game?

Comment: Does "*complete-information*" mean that both players know the values of $a$ and $\bar b$? If so, why are the bids not expressed as $b_i\in[\bar b, a)$? If not, what do they actually know?

Comment: Yes. Complete information here means that every aspect of the model is common knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any pure strategy of bidding less than $\bar b$ or more than $a$ is dominated by respectively a pure strategy of bidding $\bar b$ or bidding $a$. Therefore we can assume that $\bar b \le b_i \le a$.

Consider the payoff function of the game if we offset both $\bar b$ and $a$ by $\Delta$. If we also offset $b_i$ and $b_j$ by $\Delta$ then the differences and inequalities are invariant. So wlog we can assume that $\bar b = 0$ and that $a$ is offset appropriately. Thus we simplify the payoff function to $$\frac{\pi_i} a =\begin{cases}
1 - \frac{b_i}a & \text{if } b_i > b_j \\
(1 - \frac{b_i}a)/2 & \text{if } b_i = b_j \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

and since the Nash equilibria are unaffected by a linear scaling of the payoff function we can simplify further by assuming wlog that $a = 1$, giving $$\pi_i =\begin{cases}
1 - b_i & \text{if } b_i > b_j \\
(1 - b_i)/2 & \text{if } b_i = b_j \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Working through some small finite cases where the bids are drawn from $\{0, \frac 1 d, \frac 2 d, \ldots, 1\}$ I find that [lrs](http://banach.lse.ac.uk/) gives three extreme equilibria, all of which are pure strategies:

1. $b_i = b_j = 1$, payoff is $0$ for both players;
2. $b_i = b_j = \frac{d-1}d$, payoff is $\frac 1{2d}$ for both players;
3. $b_i = b_j = \frac{d-2}d$, payoff is $\frac 1{d}$ for both players.

In the limiting case $d \to \infty$ the first is clearly still an equilbrium (if I play $a$ then no matter what you play we both get a payoff of $0$); and the other two tend towards the first case.

So it is clearly the case that both players bidding $a$ is a Nash equilibrium; and I hypothesise that it is the only one.

Comment: Do you mean that there exist no mixed strategy equilibria?

Comment: That depends on whether you consider pure strategies to be a subset of mixed strategies or whether you consider the two sets to be disjoint.

Comment: I like your "discretized" approach. But I don't see how you can prove that there are no mixed strategy equilibria if you don't consider that agents randomize among the actions on the discretized support.

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the extreme equilbria. They're the vertices of a polytope (or, in this case, a triangle) such that any point in the polytope is a Nash equilibrium. So in the discrete case there are mixed strategies which are equilibria, being any convex sum of the three extrema, but it just happens that the extrema are pure.